# 404 Not found when using CSS resources in Vaadin13

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

I'm trying to add custom css file in Vaadin 13 project.

I added shared-styles.css file in webapp/frontend/styles/, class has annotation

```
@StyleSheet("frontend://styles/shared-styles.css")
```

but when loading a page there is a 404 error in a browser console (page is loading ok). When I try to navigate to url http://localhost:8080/frontend/styles/shared-styles.css I get

```
Could not navigate to 'frontend/styles/shared-styles.css'
Reason: Couldn't find route for 'frontend/styles/shared-styles.css'
```

Webapp folder is marked as resources.

Comment: Heve you tried just @StyleSheet("shared-styles.css") ? Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Did a quick test, works fine both with `@StyleSheet("styles/shared-styles.css")` and `@StyleSheet("frontend://styles/shared-styles.css")`. Is your webapp folder in `src/main/webapp`? And as Tatu implied, with Spring Boot the correct frontend path is `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/`.

Comment: I'm not using spring boot, this is a generic maven project from vaadin archetype, running on embedded jetty server. @StyleSheet("shared-styles.css")  is not working. The structure is src/main/webapp/frontend/styles/shared-styles.css.

Comment: "running on embedded jetty server." That implies that you should perhaps try to place styles in "frontend/styles" folder in your project instead of "src/main/webapp/frontend/styles"

Comment: @Neuro I just tested creating a new project from archetype (`13.0.13`). I then added  `shared-styles.css` to `src/main/webapp/frontend/styles`, and imported it in the `MainView` with `@StyleSheet("frontend://styles/shared-styles.css")`. Then I ran the project with `mvn jetty:run`. Worked fine, the CSS loaded correctly.

Comment: @Tazavoo which IDE do you use? I'm using IntelliJ, maybe that's a IDE specific problem?

Comment: Did the same in new, blank project. Not working :(

Comment: I'm also using IntelliJ, are you on Mac or Windows?

Comment: Windows. Are you running jetty with Run/Debug Configuration? Could you share your project with me some way?

Comment: I'm running on Mac, but tried on Windows also, works fine. I run either through the terminal, or through Run/Debug configuration, which is also Maven with goals `jetty:run`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199244/discussion-between-tazavoo-and-neuro).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because project was inside a directory which is symlinked to another location. After moving it to normal directory everything is fine.